# how to decode binary string from certificate

Tags: php

Here is my code which works completely fine and I can parse the data from the certificate. However, one of the array key's seems to have a binary encoded value, how can I go about parsing it?

```
[1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2] => �jhv�� ��X����gp
<5��߸�w��
�K;͋�G0E!���]���s�0�K/�����;#�Sdθ�� f�������E���L�,Gx�U�-=*��&,vV�/�������D�>�Fv���\�U։��K;͎=G0E -�����>�㶍���`V$���|)�u�ӡ!�J�\�i�D����'i��mN�t����K��vh���d��:���(L�qQ]g��D�
g��OO��K;͋�G0E!���  
Ct����8�/��?��Nbqŀ����� ��De�oaxLX����G`�:nY��=]����
```

Full screenshot of output here: http://prnt.sc/b87cj9

Here is the php script i am using to parse the certificate:

```
    $pemdata = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    // Small function to print the data recursivly.
    function print_element($item, $key)
    {
        if( is_array( $item ) )
        {
            echo "$key is Array:\n";
            array_walk( $item, 'print_element' );
            echo "$key done\n";
        }
        else
            echo "$key = $item\n";
    }

    // Build the PEM string.

    // Get a certificate resource from the PEM string.
    $cert = openssl_x509_read( $pemdata );

    // Parse the resource and print out the contents.
    $cert_data = openssl_x509_parse( $cert );
    //array_walk( $cert_data, 'print_element' );
    echo "<pre>".print_r($cert_data,true)."</pre>";

    // Free the resource
    openssl_x509_free( $cert );
```

Comment: Strange. Your sample code doesn't output any binary data at all on my system. Just text.

Comment: oh really? What value do you see for key [1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2] ?

Comment: I don't get that key. The keys are [name], [subject], [hash], [issuer], [version], [serialNumber], [validFrom], [validTo], [validFrom_time_t], [validTo_time_t], [signatureTypeSN], [signatureTypeLN], [signatureTypeNID], [purposes], and [extensions].

Comment: Yes, the key i am referring to is contained within the extension array - not sure why you dont see that. What version of php you running? I am on 5.6. I will take a screen grab of the output i see and post it up shortly.

Comment: can you also try this? `echo "<pre>".print_r($cert_data['extensions']['1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2'],true)."</pre>";`

Comment: 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4. It's not there, in [extensions] I get [subjectAltName], [basicConstraints], [keyUsage], [crlDistributionPoints], [certificatePolicies], [extendedKeyUsage], [authorityKeyIdentifier], [authorityInfoAccess], and [ct_precert_scts]. According to [this comment in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php#81871) it looks like PHP should be able to interpret extensions since 5.2 and return them in readable format. Nevertheless, there is code there to decode what you have which could be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112890/discussion-between-user3436467-and-matt-raines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.0.1 doesn't seem to convert all the extensions from [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) encoding to readable text.

Upgrade to 1.0.2 to fix this problem and get `ct_precert_scts` where you have `1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2`.

Comment: Thx Matt Raines. Updating openssl on the server resolved the problem and allowed php to read the extensions correctly.